# как посадить готовый сайт на wordpress?

Tags: html, wordpress, cms

Имеются сверстанные 8 страниц с Bootstrap, версталось изначально не под `WP`, то есть просто `CSS`, `JPG`, `JS` и `HTML` файлики для каждой страницы. Мне нужно интегрировать все это на вордпресс с возможностью редактирования хотя бы текстового контента из админки.

Я посмотрел несколько статей и видеотуториалов, везде из готовой верстки делается новый шаблон для `WP`, вопрос чисто для понимания происходящего, можно ли взять тему-пустышку из underscore и грубо говоря распихать код из имеющихся `HTML` файлов по `PHP` файлам пустого шаблона (`header.php`, `footer.php`, `index.php`, `functions.php`), и если да, то нужно ли для каждой страницы создавать новый `page.php`?

Если что то из написанного выше неправильно, то напишите пожалуйста краткий алгоритм посадки.

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь пожалуйста используйте обрамление кода ` только для кода. Не надо оборачивать все языки и технологии в эти метки.

Comment: Да все можно, как говорится. Вопрос в трудозатратах. Но если уж заплатили, то другого способа и нет. Можно не создавать page.php для каждой страницы, а воткнуть html-код в страницы через админку. Но заказчику потом придется править это все в html, само собой.

Comment: Все верно. Отдельный темплейт создаете для каждого типа страниц.

Comment: еще такой вопрос, существуют ли какие то метки или теги в wp, в которые можно было бы обвернуть блок с текстом, который в последствии заказчик при желании может поменять в настройках темы или управление подобным контентом создается совсем по-другому?

Comment: @АлексейКостецкий не совсем понятно, о чем речь, но, может быть, шорткоды WordPress помогут?

Answer (score 1):

Ответ просто для понимания :) да, можно взять тему-пустышку и раскидать код по файлам шапки, подвала и т. д.
Трудности у вас могут возникнуть с навигационным меню, если вы захотите сделать его настраиваемым, а не жёстко зашить в код. Обычно меню, созданные с помощью всяких конструкторов типа бутстрапа, вызывают у новичков дикие сложности в процессе интеграции, будьте к этому готовы.

Для каждой страницы делать свой шаблон `page-slug.php` нужно только в том случае, если страницы не типовые и сильно различаются своей структурой. В противном случае одного шаблона будет достаточно.

В самом общем случае, если код шапки вы разместите в файле `header.php`, код подвала - в файле `footer.php`, код `page.php` будет выглядеть примерно следующим образом:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div ... > <!-- какая-то разметка до начала текстового содержимого и прочее -->
<?php if (have_posts()) { // классика, читать гугл по запросу "wordpress the loop"
    the_post();
    ?><h1><?php the_title();?></h1><?php  // заголовок страницы
    ?><div><?php the_content();?></div><?php  // тело страницы
} ?>
</div><!-- закрываем теги обвязки, если они были -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Страницы, созданные в админке WP на вкладке "Страницы" (не "Записи"), будут выводиться с использованием этого шаблона.

Для записей по тому же принципу создаётся шаблон `single.php`

Answer (score 0):

> Если что то из написанного выше неправильно, то напишите пожалуйста
>   краткий алгоритм посадки.

1. Забыть про "сверстанные 8 страниц с бутстрапом". :)
2. Установить ВП и заполнить его контентом из этих страниц.
3. Выбрать из [оф каталога](https://ru.wordpress.org/themes/) тему, подходящую по структуре (демки смотреть на сайтах производителя, а не в каталоге!)
4. Создать [дочернюю тему](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) и использовать в ней свои стили и картинки.

Comment: А если человек за дизайн с версткой платил деньги, точно ему надо забыть про них, вы уверены?

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь, Да, уверен.